# What is required to create web site in android application by using eclipse 3.7?

Tags: android, web

If I want to create web site in android application by using eclipse 3.7 then what I required for that?

I have eclipse 3.7.0, and android 2.2 AVD.

I have a web site which is already exist but when user use the mobile he have to display mobile view so what I have to do first?

Is it required html5 and css? If yes then how can I use it?

like
[image: this is a example I want o do like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to have native app? Do you want app which user can download from playstore and this app will display your website? If so, you can create simple android app and as view use webview. Into this webview you can load website from url or local file.

You can also check out [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

Comment: if i want www.abc.com site ,displays diffently in android mobile.... so what should i do as ur opinio??

Comment: I think that what you are trying to do is not an android app, but just a version of your website for phones. In taht cse, this is not the right place.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have a native Android app (which ONLY runs on Android devices), [this](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) website will be a good starting point.

Furthermore, try to program some simple 'example' app's first to learn the language.